# McFadden's R2 > 1?

Tags: r-squared

I calculated a McFadden's R2 = 1.94094. Repeatedly. What have I done wrong? Is it inappropriate to use McFadden's R2 for conditional maximum likelihood?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about how you're computing it, so there's no way we could identify what you're doing wrong!  How about providing some context so we can help you out?

Comment: This is impossible. The log likelihood function value is always negative. Please post the log likelihood values in the optimum.

Comment: @Repmat As the likeihood is not defined as less than 1, that's not correct in general. Likelihoods as products of densities can be positive. The matter is further complicated by any conventions to omit constants that don't affect the position of the maximum.

Comment: Oops, in my mind OP was asking in relations to binary response models. Don't know where I got that from.

Answer (score 1):

So we will still need to that log-likelihood function, but it is possible that the Mcfadden r-squared is larger than 1. But it is not something that will happen often. Suppose for example that:

$$
R^2_{MC} = 1 - \frac{LogLik_{unrestricted }}{LogLik_{restricted}}= 1 - \frac{1}{-3} = 1.33
$$

Or you could reverse the sign in the fraction. In any case, the button line is that you need one of the log-likelihood functions to actually be positive in order for this to happen. Otherwise you made some mistake.

Now a positive log-likelihood function can happen, and does not automatically mean that you made some mistake.